# Deleting MythTV logs

Tags: linux, permissions, rm, mythtv

My TV software setup stopped working recently. I tracked down the issue to a lack of disk space and and ran `ncdu` to check what was up. Turns out, MythTV logs are consuming nearly 1GB of space on my little SD card. However, attempting to delete any of the log files gives me a `Permission denied` error, even when using `sudo` (this in itself confuses me because I thought a super user could do *anything*).

The owner of the `/var/log/mythtv` directory is `mythtv` and the change content permission is set to `Only owner`. Alas, attempting to change this also yields a `Permission denied` error.

I have tried logging in as `mythtv` but I don't know the password because I never set this user up.

I even tried this, which I pieced together from various searches:

`sudo -u mythtv find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.log" -print0 | xargs -0 rm`

It also fails with `Permission denied`.

Can anyone tell me how I can clean up these files?

Answer (score 1):

Your `xargs rm` command isn't getting run by the mythtv user, add `sudo` in front of it to run as a "superuser", like:

```
... | sudo xargs -0 rm
```

But do be careful with it, deleting any file can be dangerous. Or use the `-u mythtv` user option as before.